# android fragment backpress

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having 4 fragments namely A B C D.
Now When i more from A to B, I add A to back stack.
than I move from B to C without adding to back stack.
than I move from C to D without adding to back stack.
now on back press I am redirected to A.

Again I repeat till D and now when I back press, It displays fragment A and again redirects me to fragment D and on Back press again, it exits app.

I want it to be like On back press from D It should always get me to A

can anyone help?

here is the code
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bwt5u0ivqfvPSmxNN0V4YkNKa1U&usp=sharing

I am getting this in logcat

02-06 13:31:19.395  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.isTransitionGroup, referenced from method 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.captureTransitioningViews

02-06 13:31:19.395  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11340: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.isTransitionGroup ()Z

02-06 13:31:19.395  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.View.getTransitionName, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.findNamedViews

02-06 13:31:19.395  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11182: Landroid/view/View;.getTransitionName ()Ljava/lang/String;

02-06 13:31:19.405  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.View.getTransitionName, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.getTransitionName

02-06 13:31:19.405  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11182: Landroid/view/View;.getTransitionName ()Ljava/lang/String;

02-06 13:31:19.415  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1; (1303)

02-06 13:31:19.415  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1;' failed

02-06 13:31:19.415  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1', referenced from method
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setEpicenter

02-06 13:31:19.425  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 294
(Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;

02-06 13:31:19.425  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3; (1303)

02-06 13:31:19.425  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;' failed

02-06 13:31:19.435  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$3', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setSharedElementEpicenter

02-06 13:31:19.435  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 296 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;

02-06 13:31:19.435  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1; (1303)

02-06 13:31:19.435  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1;' failed

02-06 13:31:19.445  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3; (1303)

02-06 13:31:19.445  26930-26930/com.example.user.fragmentbackstackexample W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;' failed

Comment: It hard to say without seeing some code...

Comment: @KirillVolkov please check out code

Comment: That's just giving your entire source code.Please paste the relevant bits here,

Answer (score 0):

Do this..
For Fragment A do this..

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.containerMain, new FragmentA()).addToBackStack("BACKSTACK_FRAGMENT_A")
                .commit();
```

For other Fragments just do not use **addToBackStack(..)**

Now you'll always return to Fragment A when you press back from other Fragments.

UPDATE:

In your MainActivity.java do this..

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content,new FragmentA()).addToBackStack("BACKSTACK_FRAGMENT_A").commit();
```

And in your FragmentA.java do this..

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ((Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.buttonA)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setFragment(new FragmentB());
        }
    });
}
```

FINAL UPDATE:

The easiest approach to achieve your desire..

In your **MainActivity.java** do this..

```
public String TAG = "";

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (TAG.equals("FragmentD")) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new FragmentA()).commit();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

And in **every** fragment do this..

```
MainActivity mainActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
    mainActivity.TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

Hope it helps.Thanks!! ;D

Comment: I have done that only... check out code <https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bwt5u0ivqfvPSmxNN0V4YkNKa1U&usp=sharing>

Comment: If you only add Fragment A to backstack, then you can restore to fragment A only.

Comment: That's what you wanted after all!! 
"I want it to be like On back press from D It should always get me to A"

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `super.onBackPressed();` from your codes