# Fragment onback button press android skip fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 4 Fragments A B C D.
how to use back stack and how to set fragments?
I want to add just Fragment A to stack and when I press back button from B C or D, I want to to set fragment A.
I dont want B C and D in back stack

Answer (score 0):

Normally in your `FragmentTransaction` you should call `addToBackstack(null)` to add it into backstack.

The backstack is actually a stack where you pop a Fragment when user presses back.

So if A puts B, B puts C and C puts D; you cannot go from D to A directly.

You can override `onBackPressed()` and control the behavior yourself without using the Fragment's builtin back stack support.

Comment: I am adding just A fragment in stack

Comment: You still didn't give the whole story. Can you give the exactly what you want? You are adding A to the stack ok. But which one comes after which?

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337999/android-fragment-backpress/28339373?noredirect=1#comment45027213_28339373)

Answer (score 0):

You can popbackstack to clear any fragments in history and ad to backstack fragment A like so :

```
//create an instance of the fragment you want o be avilable on back press
FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

//Create instance of the fragment that is going to be loaded
FragmentD fragmentD = new FragmentD();

//Replace the current fragment with Fragment D 
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragmentD);

//Clear frgament history and include the fragment wanted on back press
fragmentManager.popBackStack();

fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentA.getclass().getName());

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```